# Insert does not working on Service Based Database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a service based database in visual studio 2017. It works with a select statement but INSERT statement doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RestaurantApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SerinCafe.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Product (Id, ProductDescription, UnitPrice, SystemDate) Values (1,'Çay', 1, '01.01.2017')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

I saw the same problem on different topics but there wasn't a clear solution that applies for me.

EDIT: On the SQL Server Object Explorer there is another database under the folder debug/bin. Now I checked it and I saw that data is inserted as I wanted. But it doesn't stay same. I changed the sql query as id = 3 and checked again. Previous data has gone. Newly inserted data is only there.

Comment: what errror do you get?

Comment: I dont get any error. It completes without error. But when I ended the program, it doesn't insert anything.

Comment: And you've verified in SQL that the rows aren't there; not just through your app, but directly against the database? TBH the select looks more suspect to me than the insert.

Comment: I have controlled it on visual studio manually. and also on the app by selecting.

Comment: Use `Server Explorer` window, add a connection to your database file and see if there are any rows in `Product` table.

Comment: I have edited. @Jalal

Comment: @alisrn Where is main `.mdf` database file? Is it in your Solution Explorer? Probably it's being copied to `bin\debug` folder each time you build the project.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you have a couple of things in that insert statement that are not so great. First you have nvarchar data but your string literal is varchar. You need to use N'Çay'. Also your date will work in most cases but not always because of date formats, You should use the ANSI standard YYYYMMDD. In your case '20170101'. That will work with any language and will always be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Mdf file is here. C:\USERS\ALI\SOURCE\REPOS\RESTAURANTAPP\RESTAURANTAPP\SERINCAFE.MDF and my solution is in C:\Users\ali\source\repos\RestaurantApp\RestaurantApp.sln @Jalal

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. I will edit those things. I am focused on inserting right now. :)

Comment: I understand it isn't the problem you are facing currently but if you don't fix those you will be back to get that part fixed. :)

Comment: @alisrn If you can see database in Solution Explorer window, right click on it and select properties. In properties window set `Copy to Local` to `Never`

Comment: It worked. Now it added and didn't deleted the old one. So how am I gonna work now? The real database is in the debug folder? It kind of confused me. Can you explain? Or at least recommend a reading?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code it works fine.Make sure you provided the connection string correctly.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer